# Is this proof correct or incorrect? If not what is the mistake?

Tags: complex-numbers, solution-verification, exponentiation

According to euler's formula
\begin{equation}
e^{i\pi}=-1 \tag{1}
\label{1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
e^{-i\pi}=-1 \tag{2}
\end{equation}

Comparing $(1)$ and $(2)$, we get

$$ e^{i\pi}=e^{-i\pi} $$

Comparing the exponents on both sides,
$$i\pi=-i\pi$$
Simplifying yields
$$i=-i$$
Is this correct? If not, what is the mistake?

Comment: Please use MathJax when writing mathematics. You can follow this link for a resource on how to format your post: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: The complex exponential function is not one-to-one.  You have just proved this!

Comment: Search tip: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fake-proofs?tab=Frequent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a function $f$, for which $f(x_1)=f(x_2)\nRightarrow x_1=x_2$. Such a function is not [injective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function). In your case $f(z)=e^z, z\in\mathbb C$. A simpler problem, which relies on the same principle is: Choose $f(x)=x^2, x\in\mathbb R$. Then  $f(3)=3^2=9$ and $f(-3)=(-3)^2=9$. Does this mean that $3=-3$?

Answer (score 3):

Let's work with your reasoning. You have
$$
e^{2\pi i} =1=e^0. 
$$
So $2\pi i =0$. Is this correct?

No, of course not. All you can say, if $e^{it}=e^{is}$, is that $s-t$ is an integer multiple of $2\pi i$. In your case, $i\pi=-i\pi +2\pi i$.

Comment: I did'nt understood.Can you please tell me some more.

Comment: @AbdullahJavaidSiddiqii $\sin(\pi) = \sin(0)$ does not simplify to $\pi = 0$.  $1^2 = (-1)^2$ does not simplify to $1=-1$.